# Oracle SQL3 3 nesting tables insert problem

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm making an SQL3 script where I create types and then create tables and nested tables. 
The prolem I'm getting happens when I want to insert a row where it says :

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got CHAR

this is an online reproduction of the problem where the types and tables are already created, you can try to insert: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/oracle_terminal_online.php?fbclid=IwAR0GgaLe2_GvGsEb80eB-D0uKDSDJDr1WNBPiK3mHQqpJQrtfacQ1cf03NA

the following is the types creation script

```
CREATE TYPE T_Personne ;
/

CREATE TYPE T_SET_Tag AS TABLE OF Varchar2(30);
/

CREATE TYPE T_Message AS OBJECT (
    Texte Varchar2(500),
    DateEcrit Date,
    Tags T_SET_Tag
);
/

CREATE TYPE T_SET_Message AS TABLE OF T_Message;
/

CREATE TYPE T_Contact AS OBJECT(
    Per REF T_Personne,
    Depuis Date
);
/

CREATE TYPE T_SET_Contact AS TABLE OF T_Contact;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_Personne AS OBJECT (
    Prenom Varchar2(30),
    Suit T_SET_Contact,
    Ecrit T_SET_Message
);
/
```

this one is the table creation script

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_Personne OF T_Personne
    NESTED TABLE Suit STORE AS TAB_suit,
    NESTED TABLE Ecrit STORE AS TAB_ecrit(
        NESTED TABLE Tags STORE AS TAB_Tags
    );
```

and finally the script I'm using to insert my new rows

```
INSERT INTO TAB_Personne VALUES( 
    'Baam',
    T_SET_Contact(),
    T_SET_Message()
);

INSERT INTO TAB_Personne VALUES( 
    'Rachel',
    T_SET_Contact(
        (SELECT REF(P)
        FROM TAB_Personne P
        WHERE P.Prenom='Baam'), 
        to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
    ),
    T_SET_Message(
        'Paris candidat aux jeux Olympiques 2022',
        to_date('01/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
        T_SET_Tag('JM2022')
    )
);
```

the error message I'm getting is

> 1 row created.
>
> ```
>   'Paris candidat aux jeux Olympiques 2022',      *
> ```
>
> ERROR at line 10:
>
> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got CHAR

I'd be glad if anyone can guide me through this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying a `T_SET_Message` collection but you then need `T_Message` objects within that; you're supplying the attributes of that object type, not an actual object of the type. The first element in the (non-)collection is a string, hence the error you get - you've supplied a string (`'Paris...'`) when it's expecting to see a UDT (`T_Message('Paris...', ...)`).

You are also doing the same thing with the `T_SET_Contact` collection.

You need to wrap your current attributes in object constructors; so this works:

```
INSERT INTO TAB_Personne VALUES( 
    'Rachel',
    T_SET_Contact(
        T_Contact(
            (SELECT REF(P)
            FROM TAB_Personne P
            WHERE P.Prenom='Baam'), 
            to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
        )
    ),
    T_SET_Message(
        T_Message(
            'Paris candidat aux jeux Olympiques 2022',
            to_date('01/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
            T_SET_Tag('JM2022')
        )
    )
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=126b1ad18275dc66116c66c3a111cee1)